# enable to open incontrollable path

Tags: python, path

I have a problem with my python code: what I want to do is ask the user to enter the path to a file and then open  and process 
the problem here is that I have no control over what the user can enter and in the case for example where the path is:`"C:\0_dir\test\file.txt"` I can not open the file and when I try to print the given path I get this:`"C: _dir    est ile.txt"` so that even if I try:     `my_path.replace ("\ \", "/")` it does not work .. I know slashes are the cause of the problem but I do not see how to solve this especially since I can not control the given paths 
if someone has already had this problem or if anyone has any Idea I would be grateful
thank you

**EDIT**

Thanks for the answers .. I'm not using input to get the path in fact this is a bit complicated : this is what my code looks like:

```
command=' test.exe -o"a/b/c/f.txt" -i"C:\0_dir\test\file.txt" -f"x/y/z"'
pathToFile=[x for x in command.split() if x.startswith("-i")]
my_path=pathToFile[0].replace("-i","")
mfile=open(my_path,"r")
contenu=mfile.readlines()
```

Comment: Are you using Python 2 and `input()` to get the path?

Comment: thanks for the answer.. but i'm not using input @MartijnPieters

Comment: Then why are you saying you are asking the user for the path?

Comment: @MartijnPieters because the command is a variable I build depending on  what user enters .. I just use it I just gave an example on my post :-)

Comment: ponder the difference between: `'\0\t\f'` and `r'\0\t\f'`. It is *very unlikely* that a user inputs the former rather than the latter. There is a difference between what you see in Python string literal and the content of the string in memory.

Comment: Thanks @J.F.Sebastian For the answer preceding the variable command with r resolves actually the problem :-) but is there any python code to transform it with python (without adding manually the letter "r" .. Thanks

Comment: `r''` is used only for literals. There is no `r''` inside strings in memory `"\\t" == r"\t"`. Just try it: `command = raw_input('input command and press Enter: ')`

Comment: the problem is I don't input command directly I don't use command=input("enter command") I gather informations in my application to build the command .. now the question is how can I transform it after building it to a raw string .. Thanks fot the help :-)

Comment: If you are reading the command from a file: `command = open(r'c:\path\to\command.txt').read()` or it is given on the command line: `command = sys.argv[1]` or any other way that doesn't involve Python string literals then you don't need to do anything: `command` is already a string object. there are **no raw strings** (objects), only raw-string **literals** i.e., unless you type the string in Python source code yourself (as in your question) or you are trying to interpret user input as Python code (`input()` on Python 2) then you shouldn't care about it.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suspect you are using the `input()` function, in Python 2, to ask the user for path input. If so, you really want to use `raw_input()` instead.

`input()` tries to interpret the given user text as a Python expression, at which point your users have to use quotes around the path, and either use *forward* slashes (which work too on Windows), a raw string literal (`r"C:\0_dir\test\file.txt"`) or double the slashes, otherwise the backslash can be interpreted as the start of an escape sequence; `\0` is interpreted as an octal byte value, `\t` is a tab and `\f` as a form feed control code.

Using `raw_input()` you'd have none of those problems:

```
>>> input('Give a path: ')
Give a path: "C:\0_dir\test\file.txt"
'C:\x00_dir\test\x0cile.txt'
>>> raw_input('Give a path: ')
Give a path: C:\0_dir\test\file.txt
'C:\\0_dir\\test\\file.txt'
```

where Python echos back the resulting value as a valid Python string literal, using escape sequences for non-printable characters (such as the null-byte and the tab character) and doubles the slashes to escape them. The actual *value* of the string has single slashes:

```
>>> print 'C:\\0_dir\\test\\file.txt'
C:\0_dir\test\file.txt
```

Your posted code should use doubled backslashes instead:

```
command = 'test.exe -o"a/b/c/f.txt" -i"C:\\0_dir\\test\\file.txt" -f"x/y/z"'
```

and your code is not removing the quotes, that are still part of the string.